What will happen if we consider an effective field theory with an explicit physical cutoff in a FRW metric?
In curved space time, quantization is done with respect to comoving wavelength. So as the universe expand, we have more and more comoving modes if we fix a physical cutoff scale. That confuses me immensely. Any comment on this subject?

What is confusing about it? Validity of the EFT?

@QuantumEyedea because mode previously integrated out nowredshifts below the cutoff, making the concept of cutoff ill-defined in cosmological context.

The cutoff you want to make is a hard-cutoff that is dependent upon the comoving scales. Actually, an easier way to formulate the problem is to put de-Sitter space in conformal time so you have $ds^2 = a^2(\tau)(-d\eta^2 + d\mathbf{x}^2)$, where $a(\eta) = -1/H\eta$, Wick rotate $\eta$ to get a Euclidean metric, and then match the Euclidean dS-space (EdS) to that of Euclidean AdS (EAdS) where in EAdS $ds^2 = L^2/z^2(dz^2+d\mathbf{x}^2)$. Then the hard-cutoff, which is different than the physical momentum modes, is $\Lambda_{\text{cutoff}}\propto |pL|$ (I think if I can recall correctly).
